# PayPal Mass Payments discontinued. Any alternative?

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is there any alternative for using PayPal Mass Payments that is both worldwide and automated?

I am to create a periodic payouts functionality on a set day of the month for an online marketplace. It should be as automated as possible, preferably only requiring admin action if the payout can not be completed for some reason.

The code worked fine in the sandbox, but when we tried to test it with live credentials we got the following error though:

```
:Errors => {
  :ShortMessage => "User is blocked",
  :LongMessage => "We're sorry, but your PayPal account isn't currently eligible to send mass payments. Please contact either PayPal Customer Service or your account manager.",
  :ErrorCode=>"10329",
  :SeverityCode=>"Error"
}
```

When the client got in touch with PayPal he was told they do not enable Mass Payments for new accounts any more and the feature is in maintenance mode only, which leaves us in quite a pinch.

I took a look at Adaptive Payments, but from what I gathered from the docs it looks like it would require interaction from the person issuing the payment, which in this case would be us - we would have to have an admin click through the PayPal confirmation page on each payout day. It'd be manageable for a beta period, but not when we go out in the public.

Is there anything else on the market that fills the same niche as PayPal Mass Payments? Or maybe I am wrong and Adaptive Payments does have a hands-free mode I missed in the docs?
Or do we have to contend with manually going through PayPal confirmation process with Adaptive Payments?
Any pointers would be appreciated.

I'm using Ruby and Rails, but non-language-based answer or an answer with a sample in any programming language will suffice, I can work out the Ruby code myself given some pointers.

Comment: Can you send me over the client's PayPal account email address? Email is in my profile, or log a ticket at https://www.paypal.com/mts and let me know the ticket number. I'll see what I can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new way to get Payouts and Mass Payments turned on, on your account.  There's also a new REST based Payouts API, which is related to Mass Payments.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/

Head over to My account to get started with your Payouts application.

Comment: Just to add on this, there would be SDKs support coming soon for all REST based SDKs for PHP, Java, .Net, Ruby, Python, NodeJS.

Comment: Individual payouts or REST API are under same restrictions as Mass Payments API.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I work at TransferWise.

Have you considered TransferWise's payouts solution? We offer an API that let's you fully automate payouts globally (50 currencies available and growing).

We're offering a similar solution, but we pay out straight to the payee's local bank.

We're also a whole lot cheaper than Paypal for international payments. Price comparison research we did here: https://transferwise.com/us/blog/transferwise-vs-paypal-savings

Marketing page here
http://transferwise.com/payouts

Api documentation here
https://api-docs.transferwise.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at Stripe, Braintree and Worldpay.

Stripe would be my preference.

You'll have to take users card details, store the token provided by Stripe, then write a module that allows you to take the payments in one go.

Comment: Well, we had Stripe payouts before, but had to deactivate that functionality as my client is Canada-based and Stripe payouts unfortunately do not work there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at VerifyValid.  They do mass payouts.